# Touch-changing chart for iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, graph

By searching a bit I found many libraries to create some charts for the iPhone. Just want to ask if someone has ever worked with a library where the end user can touch the graph and edit it. For example touch a bar graph and make a bar taller or shorter and get back the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to accomplish this with [core plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/). the built in touch tracking can tell you where the user is touching, from there you'd just change the height of that bar and reload the graph.

Comment: +1 for pointing me in a direction. You'll have to wait for accepting the answer cause I need to try it first

Comment: absolutely right! thanks